# Is there a way to reset chrome://flags to their defaults?

Tags: google-chrome

I was messing around with `chrome://flags/`, and don't remember all the changes I made. Now I want to get it back to its default state.

Since I use Sync, does reinstalling Chrome do it? Or better yet, is there a way to do it without reinstalling?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the record, now there is a Reset button on the flags page.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

#### Manual reset

Flags that can be enabled or disabled have gray font color in their description if set to their default value. The description of altered flags is black.

All drop-down menus should be set to **Default** or **Automatic**.

#### Override

Invoking Chrome with the command-line switch `--no-experiments` doesn't revert the changes made in `chrome://flags`, but it ignores them entirely.

Comment: Perfect, didn't notice that.

Comment: This is gold! This is for when chrome won't even launch because of your tinkering.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows, to reset FLAGS:

- Close Chrome.
- Open via Notepad: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State`
- Find line staring with `enabled_labs_experiments`
- Delete this whole line and save file.

Answer (score 0):

This resolution is for a Linux build (Ubuntu 16.04) Chromium 56 to 58.3019.
I broke chromium after activating a flag related to be attempting to get Chromium exclusively to cast to my chrome cast device. Chromium would crash after being open for a second, spat out error code: Signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR, + memory log. I had an misc. error due to invalid codec but that was of my own folly so I'll digress on that point as it it's resolved.

After realizing chromium did work in guest mode I assessed it was an setting/config issue. I couldn't pinpoint / access the flags to restore functions. So I deleted the chromium folder within /.config/chromium from terminal. Thereby resetting  chromium to default values all over, re-login and re-sync. 
'cd .config' 
'rm -rvf chromium'