# How to copy Chrome's flags from a different Google account?

Tags: google-chrome, crash

After adjusting `chrome://flags/` Chrome is crashing completely.  I can't revert anything because of the "aw snap" and crashing. I wish to reset all flags from a different Google account, like a mirror. Is this possible? and how?

Comment: Re-install chrome

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/575374/is-there-a-way-to-reset-chrome-flags-to-their-defaults